# How can I configure the Linux terminal to only line feed (and not carriage return) when outputting a "\n"?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, newline, carriage-return

When I run a program that outputs "\n" to the terminal, I'd like to configure the terminal beforehand (perhaps via stty) to not do a Carriage Return, but to only move the cursor down a row.  To actually consider it a Line Feed, and not to perform a Carriage Return.

For example, if the program prints "123\n456", I would like to see:

```
123
   456
```

but I, of course, currently see:

```
123
456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man stty` says:

```
   * [-]onlcr
          translate newline to carriage return-newline
```

So we can turn it off, print something, and turn it on again:

```
$ stty -onlcr; printf '\rfoo\nbar\r\n'; stty onlcr
foo
   bar
```