# How to Echo Newline ("\x0A") Without Appended Carriage Return ("\x0D")

Tags: linux, terminal, newline, uart, carriage-return

I am trying to transfer individual bytes from a binary file over UART from a Linux MPU to a separate MCU. The code I am using to transfer the data is shown below:

```
echo -ne $data > /dev/ttyS1
```

This code has been working great for me except for in one situation when the data includes a hex value of `\x0A` (newline character). Whenever I echo the `\x0A` value with the code above, it actually sends `\x0D\x0A` (carriage return and newline character). Because of this, I get errors in my binary file transfer.

I have tried sending the following commands:

```
echo -ne "\x0A" > /dev/ttyS1
echo -ne "\n" > /dev/ttyS1
```

When I do that, the UART bus is showing the 0x0D0A transfer as shown in the image below.

[image: UART Transfer]

Is there a way I can force the echo to just send the 0x0A character without the 0x0D character appended to it?

Comment: try using `printf` instead. good luck

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71524964/103167 (except that you're using the shell, so you'll need the `stty` command instead of calling OS functions).  Try `stty -F /dev/ttyS1 raw`

Comment: as said, you need to [use raw mode instead of cooked mod](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70922286/995714)

Comment: Those articles about configuring the Linux terminal did resolve my question. I somehow missed that setting in the STTY configuration. Thanks for your help!